# I have a select query that returns a count value

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me with the update command

```
select guest_no,count(flag_booking) 
from booking 
where flag_booking = 'C' 
group by guest_no;
```

Now I want to update this using the update command i.e. update the field that will contain the count of flag_booking  for every different guest separately

```
update guest 
set complete_booking = (
    select count(*) 
    from booking 
    join guest on guest.guest_no = booking.guest_no 
    group by guest.guest_no,guest.flag_booking 
    having guest.flag_booking = 'C'
) ;
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *correlate* the subquery:

```
update guestg g
set complete_booking = (
    select count(*) 
    from booking b
    where g.guest_no = b.guest_no and b.flag_booking = 'C'
) ;
```

In this query, the subquery returns just one record, with a unique column that contains the count of bookings for the concerned guest. Hence you don't need to `group by`, nor to `join`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
update guest g
  set complete_booking = (select count(*) 
                          from booking b
                          where b.guest_no = g.guest_no and
                                b.flag_booking = 'C'
                         ) ;
```

The `join` and `group by` do not do what you want.  First, the `group by` is probably going to return multiple rows, which will result in a run-time failure of the query.  Second, the subquery is not related to the outer query, so all rows would get the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a join in the subquery, nor a group by:

```
update guest 
  set complete_booking = (select count(*) 
                          from booking 
                          where guest.guest_no = booking.guest_no) 
                            and booking.flag_booking = 'C');
```